# Generic method arguments in scala

Tags: scala

I'm not sure the title is describing my question the best but let's give it a shot.

I have a background job execution application that resembles a simple pipeline processing. There are `Command` objects that do some calculation and return an `OUTPUT`, and `Worker` that receive `OUTPUT` as input and can return `Result`
The object model looks something like this:

```
type OUTPUT <: AnyRef
trait Command[OUTPUT] {
  def doSomething(): OUTPUT
}
sealed trait Worker[IN <: AnyRef, OUT <: Result] {
  def work(input: IN): OUT
}

case class WorkA() extends Worker[String, LongResult] {
  override def work(input: String): LongResult = LongResult(Long.MaxValue)
}

case class WorkB() extends Worker[Long, StringResult] {
  override def work(input: Long): StringResult = StringResult(input.toString)
}
```

There are few problems with this approach:

When mapping on a collection of `Worker` I can't make sure the worker accepts the same `OUTPUT` as input.

Unless I'm mapping a List of `Command`, the code does not compile because of type erasure - it expects a `_$1` but receives a `Long` or a `String` (everything that was previously accepted as `OUTPUT`)

```
val workers = List(
  new WorkA(),
  new WorkB()
)

val aSimpleCommand = new Command[Long] {
  override def doSomething() = 123123123L
}
// Obviously this doesn't compile.
workers.map(worker => worker.work(aSimpleCommand.doSomething()))
```

I'm looking for the right Scala mechanism to disallow this at compile time. How can I map ONLY on the Worker that DO actually support `OUTPUT` - and in this case, only `WorkB`

Comment: You intention is not clear here. List `workers` has 1 worker that accepts a `String`, and another worker, that accepts `Long`. `aSimpleCommand.doSomething` returns a `Long`, but using `map` you try to pass it to `WorkA`, which wants a `String`. Of course it can't compile.

Comment: Exactly @Kolmar. I'm looking for the right Scala mechanism to disallow this at compile time. How can I map ONLY on the `Worker` that DO actually support `OUTPUT` - and in this case, only `WorkB`

Comment: I think @Kolmar's point is that this is _already_ disallowed at compile time - I am guessing you mean how do you disallow it at _runtime_ (ie. have it compile happily, but filter out inappropriate workers at runtime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this at compile time you can use shapeless HLists, preserving the type of your list all the way through, and then using a `Poly` to handle the cases:

```
val myWorkers: WorkA :: WorkB :: WorkB :: HNil =
  WorkA() :: WorkB() :: WorkB() :: HNil

object doWork extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseLong[A] = at[Worker[Long, A]] {
    w => w.work(aSimpleCommand.doSomething())}
  implicit def caseString = //whatever you want to do with a String worker
}

myWorkers map doWork
```

For a less safe example that doesn't need shapeless, you can match cases as long as you have concrete types:

```
val myWorkers: List[Worker[_, _]] = ...
myWorkers collect {
  case wa: WorkA => //works
  case lw: Worker[Long, _] => //doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Shapeless is awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is feasible to explicitly state all classes that extend `Worker[Long, _]`, then you could map the workers over a partial function like so:

```
val res = workers map {
  case b: WorkB => Some(b.work(aSimpleCommand.doSomething()))
  case _ => None
}
```

In your example, this will return `List(None, Some(StringResult(123123123))`. You can also collect only the existing values:

```
res collect {case Some(r) => r} // List(StringResult(123123123))
```

---

Now, this isn't a very practical solution. Maybe the following thoughts help you come up with something better:

As you have already stated, because of type erasure, we cannot create our partial function to accept values of type `Worker[Long, _]` at runtime. `ClassTag` (and `TypeTag`) provide a solution to this problem by making the compiler create evidence accessible at runtime for the erased types. For example, the following function extracts the runtime class of a worker's input:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def getRuntimeClassOfInput[T: ClassTag](worker: Worker[T, _]) = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass
```

Example usage:

```
println(getRuntimeClassOfInput(new WorkB)) // long
```

The problem is that this doesn't seem to work once the workers are inside a list. I suppose that it's because once you have multiple different workers in the list, the list becomes a `List[Worker[Any, Result]` and you lose all type information. What *might* solve this problem are [Heterogenous Lists](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists) because unlike the standard lists they keep the static type information of all elements.